# Change language in react-native-datepicker

Tags: react-native

how to use `locale` with the `react-native-datepicker`?

I'm using `react-native-datepicker@1.7.2` and want to change the language of `Datepicker` when the user changes the language. I tried `locale = {pa}` in `Datepicker` but the language is not changing. however when I install the `react-native-date-picker` library and use the `locale` with it. it's working fine. but I want to use only `react-native-datepicker` library.

is there is an alternate way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

`react-native-datepicker`  doesn't has locale support but someone forked then added language support like this,

```
<DatePicker
locale={'vi'}
date={this.state.date}
mode='date'/>
```

if you want use this version,

Update you `package.json` as follows:

```
"react-native-datepicker": "git+https://github.com/pablo-albaladejo/react-native-datepicker.git",
```

then

```
rm -rf node_modules && npm install
```